# Parsing and computing boolean set definitions

Tags: python, math, set, boolean, scipy

Say I have a set `S` defined as a string, e.g. as follows:

```
S = '(A or B) and not(A and C)'
```

where A, B and C are finite sets, e.g.:

```
A = {0, 1}
B = {0, 2}
C = {1, 3}
```

If we analyze `S` step by step, we have:

```
(A or B)   = {0, 1, 2}
(A & C)    = {1}
not(A & C) = {0, 2, 3}
```

which gives us the final result:

```
S = {0,2}
```

How can I compute the elements of `S` given its definition as a general boolean formula?

I don't quite know how to start addressing this problem. On one hand I wonder if I need to use a full **lexical parser**. Also, after some reading I also found two concepts that seem that highly related, but don't know how they would apply:

- [Canonical Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form)
- [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Aside: `and` and `or` may not act the way you think they do.  If you try `A = {0, 1}; B = {0, 2}; Z = A or B; print(Z)`, you won't see `{0, 1, 2}`.  OTOH, `A | B` should give what you expect.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no need to write your own parser if you're willing to transform *S* in to a string suitable for use with [*eval()*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval).  Change *S* from `'(A or B) and not(A and C)'` into an equivalent *T* that uses Python's *in*-operator `'(x in A or x in B) and not(x in A and x in C)'`.

Compute the result by looping over the universe of elements and testing whether they match the above expression.
Here's a worked-out example at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> T = '(x in A or x in B) and not(x in A and x in C)'
>>> sets = {'A': {0, 1}, 'B': {0, 2}, 'C': {1, 3}}
>>> universe = {x for s in sets.values() for x in s}
>>> {x for x in universe if eval(T, sets, {'x': x})}
set([0, 2])
```

To make the transformation automatically, create a namespace for the set variables where variable lookups do a set membership test.  Putting it all together gives you a simple and clean set-expression evaluator:

```
class SetVariables(dict):
    'Transform a variable lookup into a membership test'
    def __getitem__(self, var):
        s = dict.__getitem__(self, var)
        return self.x in s

def set_eval(expr, **sets):
    'Evaluation a set expression for the given sets'
    universe = {x for s in sets.values() for x in s}
    expr = compile(expr, '', 'eval')
    variables = SetVariables(sets)
    results = set()
    for x in universe:
        variables.x = x
        if eval(expr, {}, variables):
            results.add(x)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print set_eval(expr = '(A or B) and not(A and C)',
                   A = {0, 1},
                   B = {0, 2},
                   C = {1, 3}
                  )
```

Hope this solves your problem and saves you from having to write your own parser :-)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to use the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to convert this to Reverse Polish Notation and then use this [simple algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm) to evaluate the espression.

No need for a proper parser then, you only need to recognize each word, parens and special character composing the definition with no need of "understanding the structure of the sentence".