# Mapping Boolean formulas to Python set expressions

Tags: python, regex, parsing, boolean, numexpr

Say I have a Boolean formula that uses a known set of tokens, e.g.:

- Boolean operators: `and`, `or`, `not`
- Grouping operators: `(`, `)`

Given a Boolean formula using those tokens, e.g.:

F: `(A or B) and not(A and C)`

How can I convert this definition to a Python expression of set operators?

Fp = `(x in A or x in B) and not(x in A and x in C)`

For background on this question, see this [thread and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22316212/283296).

Comment: Not sure why you accepted the linked answer which apparently didn't really solve the general problem. Anyway, you need to parse the boolean expression. You might find the [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) module helpful. It comes with a number of examples to help you get going.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for [set operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects). You can do something like:

```
Fp = (A | B) - C
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your variables are one character in length:

```
s = "(A or B) and not(A and C)"
print re.sub("(?<![a-zA-Z])([A-Za-z])(?![A-Za-z])", "x in \\1", s)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like basically you are going to prepend `x in` to anything that is not one of your tokens. That looks like this, maybe:

```
tokens = ['and', 'or', 'not']
grouping = ['(', ')']

def resub(match):
    matchval = match.group(0)
    if matchval in tokens:
        return matchval
    return 'x in %s'%matchval

s = "(A or B) and not(A and C)"

re.sub('\w+', resub, s)
'(x in A or x in B) and not(x in A and x in C)'
```

It should work for symbols that are recognized as words; if you need something more specific (i.e. your variables have other characters in them), you'd need to define it yourself instead of using `\w`...

Answer (score 1):

This function will match against any Python identifier, will substitute for any desired target variable, and it's all wrapped up to be easy to use:

```
import re

def subst_in(s, varname, keywords={'and', 'or', 'not'}):
    repl = "{} in {{}}".format(varname)
    def fn(match):
        s = match.group(0)
        return s if s in keywords else repl.format(s)
    return re.sub("[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*", fn, s, flags=re.I)

f = "(A or B) and not(A and C)"
fp = subst_in(f, "x")
```

gives

```
'(x in A or x in B) and not(x in A and x in C)'
```

**Edit:** although frankly it should be

```
'x in B or (x in A and x not in C)'
```